# Extract email id from place details that have website

Tags: java, api, google-maps, google-places-api, openrefine

How can i extract email id based on the website that i have got from Place Details using Google maps API. 
I want to extract the generic email id from these place details or the website. I have attached a screen shot to show what i have. I am using open Refine.I am able to parse the phone number but can't parse email id's as its not present in these place details but i can see it on the website.

Thank you in advance.

This is the code i am using -

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=" + cells['PlaceID'].value + "&key=AIzaSyCSp-f-_FWHw8jfNFF9yd7mgUxaX-DZo8g"
```

[image: Output that I am getting]

Comment: Feed the String to JSON and *extract* using the JSON API.

Comment: If E-Mail is not present there, then from where do you want to extract it?

Comment: Im saying how can i get an email id from the website that is present in those details? Is there some script i can write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [google maps places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) this is not something that can be returned from the API. I believe that Google does not want its API to be used as a source for spamming companies. Based on that, I can't think of any legal option that would give you this email.

The only solution that I can think of would be to get the URL attribute from google maps API result and from then scrape the page and hope that there is a way to find the email address in the HTML code, but :

- I don't think that google would present it in a easily scrappable way;
- I believe it would go against terms of use of Google.

So to summarize I don't think there is an easy and legal solution to your question.

Comment: Hi Sylvain, how is it that i get phone numbers then ? Thanks for the detailed explanation though!

Comment: Hi @Vijay . This is because the Google place API returns a JSON answer with fields described in [https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details] (google maps places) with for example ```international_phone_number``` highlighted in your original post. As you can see on the linked page there is nothing about an email address.

Comment: "...The Contact category includes the following fields:
`formatted_phone_number`, `international_phone_number`, `opening_hours`, `website`..."
nothing else